# Extract values using regex in python

Tags: python, json, regex

How can I extract Input from the following string using regex:

```
{"eventid":"cowrie.command.input","input":"echo \"root:twrHxXE7YmIr\"|chpasswd|bash","message":"CMD: echo \"root:twrHxXE7YmIr\"|chpasswd|bash","sensor":"cowrieHoneypot2","timestamp":"2021-05-06T10:35:25.171419Z","src_ip":"121.201.95.106","session":"1ce15808ec97"}
```

Following is the regex pattern currently I'm using:

```
\"input\":\"[a-zA-z0-9\s=+~_\\$-|]*\"
```

But it returns half values like:

```
"input":"echo \"
```

So, how can I modify this regex to get the complete value?

Comment: Parse JSON with the right tool: https://ideone.com/ENlHwR

Comment: This is the [file](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/2bfd5c68-f27c-4ee9-b33a-4af9302b12f2) json not working with it.

Comment: It can still be parsed with `json`. See https://ideone.com/49l4Hm

Comment: Can I use this regex code by modifying it somewhat to use for JSON:
`
import re
import json

hand = open('cowrie.log')
outF = open("Usernames and Passwords.txt", "w")
for line in hand:
    res = re.search(r"login\sattempt\s\[[a-zA-Z0-9]'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'/[a-zA-Z0-9]+'[a-zA-Z0-9]+']", line)
    if res:
        outF.write(res.group())
        outF.write("\n")
outF.close()
`

Comment: Don't use regex with JSON. Never. It is not meant to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add commas between `}` and `{` that are separated with a newline, and it can be done with a simple `.replace("}\n{", "},\n{")`.

Then you can parse the JSON with `json` module:

```py
import json

filepath = r'PATH_TO_FILE'

with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()

j = json.loads('[{}]'.format(contents.replace("}\n{", "},\n{")))
values = [n["input"] for n in j if 'input' in n]
print(values)
```

Using your data, the output is

```
['enable', 'system', 'system', 'shell', 'shell', 'sh', 'cat /proc/mounts; /bin/busybox KUHJY', 'cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox KUHJY', 'tftp; wget; /bin/busybox KUHJY', 'dd bs=52 count=1 if=.s || cat .s || while read i; do echo $i; done < .s', 'while read i', '/bin/busybox KUHJY', 'rm .s; exit', 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name | wc -l', 'echo "root:QEqRsCr9yFa5"|chpasswd|bash', "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name | head -n 1 | awk '{print $4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9;}'", "free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $2 ,$3, $4, $5, $6, $7}'", 'ls -lh $(which ls)', 'which ls', 'crontab -l', 'w', 'uname -m', 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep model | grep name | wc -l', 'top', 'uname', 'uname -a', 'lscpu | grep Model', 'cd ~ && rm -rf .ssh && mkdir .ssh && echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEArDp4cun2lhr4KUhBGE7VvAcwdli2a8dbnrTOrbMz1+5O73fcBOx8NVbUT0bUanUV9tJ2/9p7+vD0EpZ3Tz/+0kX34uAx1RV/75GVOmNx+9EuWOnvNoaJe0QXxziIg9eLBHpgLMuakb5+BgTFB+rKJAw9u9FSTDengvS8hX1kNFS4Mjux0hJOK8rvcEmPecjdySYMb66nylAKGwCEE6WEQHmd1mUPgHwGQ0hWCwsQk13yCGPK5w6hYp5zYkFnvlC8hGmd4Ww+u97k6pfTGTUbJk14ujvcD9iUKQTTWYYjIIu5PmUux5bsZ0R4WFwdIe6+i6rBLAsPKgAySVKPRK+oRw== mdrfckr">>.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod -R go= ~/.ssh && cd ~', 'enable', 'system', 'system', 'shell', 'shell', 'sh', 'cat /proc/mounts; /bin/busybox PYIHO', 'cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox PYIHO', 'tftp; wget; /bin/busybox PYIHO', 'dd bs=52 count=1 if=.s || cat .s || while read i; do echo $i; done < .s', 'while read i', '/bin/busybox PYIHO', 'rm .s; exit', 'enable', 'system', 'system', 'shell', 'shell', 'sh', 'cat /proc/mounts; /bin/busybox GYYXE', 'cd /dev/shm; cat .s || cp /bin/echo .s; /bin/busybox GYYXE', 'tftp; wget; /bin/busybox GYYXE', 'dd bs=52 count=1 if=.s || cat .s || while read i; do echo $i; done < .s', 'while read i', '/bin/busybox GYYXE', 'rm .s; exit']
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working like a charm. can you tell how to save values directly in files instead of in an array write now I'm using array and writing it in the file in the following manner:
`hand = open('cowrie.json')

outF = open("input.txt", "w")
filepath = r'cowrie.json'
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()

j = json.loads('[{}]'.format(contents.replace("}\n{", "},\n{")))
values = [n["input"] for n in j if 'input' in n]
for commands in values:
       outF.write(commands)
       outF.write("\n")`

Comment: @ZeeshanAliQureshi `with open('data.json', 'w') as f: for l in values: f.write(f"{l}\n")`

Answer (score 0):

```
 \"input\":\"([^\,\}\"]|\\\")*\"[,\{]
```